# Prevent console log from being cleared in xcode

Tags: xcode

I am using xcode 5.1 My app logs a huge amount of data to the console. As the size of the log increases the older data is deleted. How can prevent xcode from deleting my log

Comment: Why are you using `xcode 5.1` and not `xcode 6.1`?

Comment: I have not updated yet, is it possible in 6.1

Comment: Not sure not looked but I would recommend updating. There is no point in us giving an answer for outdated software as it could have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode caps its log files to a certain size, which is why older lines are cleared out over time.

One solution is to use a third-party logging framework such as [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack) and print logs to a separate file; that way you can specify the maximum size of your log file.